# Shadow Catcher in three.js / shadow on transparent material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to cast a shadow on a boxMesh while the mesh itself should be invisible.

I've found a [technique](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1791) on three.js GitHub Issue Tracker that's seemingly been working a few years ago but doesn't anymore - it involves the creation of a new shader.

Is there any other way or an updated version of that now not anymore working trick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can cast a shadow on a mesh having a transparent material by using `THREE.ShadowMaterial`. Use this pattern:

```js
var material = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
material.opacity = 0.5;

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );
```

There is an example of its use in [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html) three.js example.

three.js r.147

Comment: hi the shadow is completly black, is it possible to give the shadow an alpha value?

Comment: It seems the material.opacity controls the darkness of the shadow? For me it's completely black at 1 but looks good at 0.2 like in the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial